# Keras CNN incompatible input

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I'm new to keras and haven't figured out the dimension rules yet. I use the TF backend and keep getting this ValueError with below code. The idea is to use 2 1D convolution layers which each need to process 1 time series array of length 6. Then the outputs of these need to merge and be convolved over in a 2D convolution layer. Thanks for the help.

```
NN1 = Sequential()
NN1.add(Convolution1D(4, 2,
                         input_dim=6,
                         activation='relu'))

NN2 = Sequential()
NN2.add(Convolution1D(4, 2,
                         input_dim=6,
                         activation='relu'))

TNN    = Sequential()
TNN.add(Merge([NN1, NN2], mode='concat', concat_axis=1))
TNN.add(Convolution2D(2, 2, 2, input_shape=(2, 4, 1, 2), activation='relu'))

ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer convolution2d_1: expected ndim=4, found ndim=3
```

Comment: Could you provide us your data shape?

Comment: The data shape will be (1, 1, 6).

Comment: This means that your input is a sequence with a one timestep?

Comment: My input will be one array containing a sequence of 6 timesteps.

Comment: So it should have shape `(nb_of_samples, timesteps, features)`

Comment: Would you mind explaining what that means for this particular network?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137860/discussion-between-marcin-mozejko-and-cpat).

Comment: I would appreciate an upvote if it's not a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After conversation I would advise you to do the following:

```
TNN.add(Merge([NN1, NN2], mode='concat', concat_axis=-1))
TNN.add(Convolution1D(2, 2, activation='relu'))
TNN.add(GlobalMaxPooling1D())
TNN.add(Dense(...)) # Put your parameters here.
```